# Mostrando preloader quando o 'Enter' é pressionado

Tags: php, jquery

Preciso que seja mostrado um preloader após a tecla 'Enter' ser pressionada numa caixa de pesquisa. Cheguei a conclusão abaixo, mas não funciona. Conseguem me dar uma ajuda?

```
        <div id="preloader">
        <div class="inner">
           <div class="">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>                    
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="x-searchform-overlay">

        <div class="x-searchform-overlay-inner">
          <div class="x-container max width">
           <?php     echo get_product_search_form(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


 <script>

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
       $('.preloader').hide();
   }
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Antes do `if` insira `e.preventDefault();` e veja se funciona.

Comment: Nenhuma mudança..

Comment: Como está sua classe .preloader. O que exatamente não está funcionando. Edita a sua pergunta e coloca mais alguns detalhes.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Aqui $('.preloader').hide(); não deveria ser $('.preloader').show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o seu `.preloader`é um `id` e não uma `class`.

você precisa inserir o jquery para funcionar:

Seu código tem que mais ou menos assim:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
       $('#preloader').show();
   }
}); 

</script>
```

O certo é colocar entre a tag `<head>`:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Exemplo:

```js
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
               alert("Apertou Enter");
           }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>CLIQUE AQUI E APERTE O ENTER</p>
```

E se for para mostrar, como dito pelo @Deividson você precisa usar o `show()`:

```
   if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
       $('#preloader').show(); // <-- show() mostra a div
   }
```

Comment: Já testei de várias formas, na verdade... Tentei com class, com id...

Comment: Erro - TypeError: $ is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: Você referenciou o Jquery?

Comment: era isso que ia falar

Comment: hm... não sei dizer.. como devo fazer essa referência?

Answer (score -1):

e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Mas ainda não deu certo...